# LXC does not stop, Failed to connect to bus

Tags: linux, shutdown, init, lxc, container

I just created a new LXC with the following command:

```
lxc-create -n ${NAME} -t download
```

I choosed `debian`, `stretch` and `amd64` as characteristics. I'm using the LXC in unprivileged mode with UID/GID mappings (`/etc/sub?id`).

The problem is that I can't stop the LXC. Within the container I get the following message (from within the LXC):

```
# shutdown -h now
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Same thing here from host-system:

```
# lxc-attach -n tmp-deb9 -- shutdown now
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

Or even like this (from within the LXC):

```
# init 0
Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn.
```

If I run the following command, it hangs forever:

```
lxc-stop -n ${NAME}
```

I tried to install `dbus` but the problem has not been solved.

I am not able to stop the LXC or kill the `init` process even from the host-system.

How could I stop the LXC?

Comment: This is more of a troubleshooting step than an answer: I had the same symptoms and when I ran `sudo ps aux` in the container it showed that systemd was not even running, causing things like `shutdown` or `sshd` to not work right.  (In my case it turned out that some fool who was *definitely not me* ran `rm -r /var/cache/` while preparing the rootfs but didn't bother to run `mkdir /var/cache` afterwards, and systemd was puking over that.)

Comment: Maybe you are hitting this one:
https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/does-ubuntu-16-04-lxc-container-work-on-ubuntu-22-04-lxd-host/15250